# GMT vs UTC dates

Tags: javascript, php, date, utc, gmt

I have a calendar built in JavaScript that compares dates with PHP. The JavaScript date object is set using PHP, but, when I compare future dates, they appear to be out of sync.

PHP is set to GMT and JavaScript is set to UTC; how do these standards differ, and could this be causing the problem?

Comment: For practical purposes (and certainly all cases a computer will see), GMT is UTC. Your timezone problem lies elsewhere. Let's see some code.

Answer (score 37):

From [Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) on Wikipedia:

> Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is a time standard based on International Atomic Time (TAI) with leap seconds added at irregular intervals to compensate for the Earth's slowing rotation.

From [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) on Wikipedia:

> UTC is an atomic time scale which only approximates GMT with a tolerance of 0.9 second

Comment: Which, for pretty much any application should be something you can ignore. Exceptions are very rare and those exceptions are very unlikely to be written in PHP anyway.

Comment: That should be UT1 not GMT.

Comment: Even more importantly: "[UTC] is one of several closely related successors to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). For most purposes, UTC is considered interchangeable with GMT, but GMT is no longer precisely defined by the scientific community"

Answer (score 35):

One is measured from the sun and another from an [atomic clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock).

For your purposes, they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

For computers, GMT is UTC+0 - so they are the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly go by the definition of what UTC and GMT are, there is no real practical difference as others have pointed out.

However one needs to be careful as there are certain cases where (possibly legacy) terminology is used such as in the [Microsoft Timezone index values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values)

The difference is that in that context, what is referred to as the "GMT timezone" (code 55) is, in reality, the "GMT locale" which is the locale used by  Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London (all of which observe daylight savings time) which is differentiated from Greenwich Standard Time (code 5A) which is used by Monrovia and Reykjavik both of which do not observe daylight savings time.

The practical difference is that if a system is set up to use UTC (code 80000050 under the semantics specified above) then it will not automatically switch to daylight savings time while if you set your time zone to GMT (code 55) then there's a good chance it automatically switches to BST during the summer without you noticing.

Comment: if you set it to "GMT" is should stay there.  if you set it to "London" it should follow the civil time rules of that locale switching to BST in the summer

Comment: @Jasen as far as I know London is not a timezone but a locale. You can set a server to the London locale but the server will then report GMT as its timezone half the year and BST for the other half. However if you don't set a locale then it will just report UTC all year round. If you're using Windows then the London locale is confusingly called GMT or BST or something ambiguous for some reason. It's just a whole can of worms you really don't want to be opening.

Comment: Totally agree WRT windows.

Comment: **Incorrect.** Do not conflate UTC/GMT with [London time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom). London time observes Daylight Saving Time (DST). UTC and GMT by definition do not. UTC/GMT is the base against which all other zones and DST are measured by an offset of some number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind. For half the year when London is not on DST, its wall-clock time happens to coincide with UTC/GMT. The geographical location of the UTC/GMT longitude happens to run through London (Greenwich) but conceptually that is irrelevant.

Comment: @BasilBourque the confusion sometimes lies when one reads the microsoft time zones like e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values where the London timezone is named GMT standard time and there's a different code for UTC. Digging deeper you can find that this is because what they call "GMT" is actually "Londong time" which can be either GMT or BST.

Comment: @apokryfos Seems like you may have a valid point. So rewrite your Answer to say *that*.  Then I’ll retract my comment and down-vote.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the note. I've clarified my point, it hopefully is more clear now.