# Converting from GMT to UTC

Tags: php, sql, oracle

In a table all the records are stored in GMT time. But through my application i want to display only those records which falls into timezone UTC. i.e., in a web page i want to display only records that comes under UTC time zone.

Converting from GMT to UTC. Or Query the database to get all the records of UTC timezone.

I really appreciate an early reply.

I am using oracle database and  application in PHP.

Comment: Isn't GMT and UTC effectively the same?

Comment: UTC has no daylight saving time

Comment: Neither does GMT, when we switch to daylight saving time in the UK that's BST (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)

Comment: @Santhosh: what is the data type of the column in which your time values are stored?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612148/gmt-vs-utc-dates 
The first comment on that question is "For practical purposes (and certainly all cases a computer will see), GMT is UTC".

Comment: Hey Thanks for all the comments... Yes, i come to know that GMT and UTC are same. If suppose i want to convert GMT to CST .i.e,. offset is -05:00.

Comment: The column type is TIMESTAMP(6) ... basically  the data will be viewed by different users in different time zone so i want to display the data according to there timezone.  All the data stored in the table is in GMT time zone ...

Answer (score 1):

From [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich%5FMean%5FTime#Ambiguity_in_the_definition_of_GMT) on Wikipedia:

> It [GMT] is arguably the same as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Regarding converting, you can add/remove intervals, but in so far as I'm aware, Oracle supports timestamps with/without time zones:

```
select now() at time zone 'UTC' as utc,
       now() at time zone 'EST' as est,
       now() at time zone 'Europe/London' as london;
```

The last example, if it works, would allow you to not worry about daylight savings and so forth.

Comment: thanks... the data type of the column is TIMESTAMP(6) .. the data will be viewed by different users in different time zone so i want to display the data according to there timezone. All the data stored in the table is in GMT time zone

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that your times are stored as DATE values, that all the values are stored as UTC times, and that the timezone you're interested in is constant.  To convert from UTC to a given timezone you add the timezone's offset.  In this case, since the timezone of interest has a negative offset you need to add in the same negative number.  Thus, the following might be useful:

```
SELECT DATE_FIELD + INTERVAL '-5' HOUR
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE <whatever>
```

FWIW, there are some places where the conversion to local time uses a non-whole-hour offset - for example, Adelaide, Australia uses a +9.5 hour offset from GMT, and Kathmandu, Nepal uses +5.75 hours.

Share and enjoy.

EDIT: Given the data as you've described it, your best bet is probably to simply add in the session time zone, as follows:

```
SELECT your_gmt_timestamp_field AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE
  FROM your_table
```

Give this a try and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks... the data type of the column is TIMESTAMP(6). Basically the data will be viewed by different users in different time zone so i want to display the data according to there timezone. All the data stored in the table is in GMT time zone